# libgdx android fragment settings

Tags: android, android-fragments, libgdx

I'm new In Android using libgdx I'd like to switch from activity to fragment.

I've read that by default Compass and Accelerometer are enabled so I disabled them by this code:

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useAccelerometer = false;
        config.useCompass = false;
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
```

Now I should modify this code to support fragment, the example provided in libgdx wiki is:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Plane plane = (Plane) getArguments().get(ARGS_PLANE);
        return initializeForView(new MyGdxGame());
    }
```

So, my questions are:

- Why should I use Plane?
- Where could I disable the compass and accelerometer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useAccelerometer = false;
    config.useCompass = false;
    return initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(), config);
}
```

I think that line about the Plane is a mistake in the documentation. It makes no sense at all.